# Dual booting fails after applying Yosemite upgrade to MacPro

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot, osx-yosemite

After applying Yosemite to my triple-boot MacBook Pro, it fails to boot either Windows or Ubuntu.

I installed rEFInd, and I can now see all three operating systems in the rEFInd menu, but when I select anything other than MacOS X, the boot fails with "No bootable media".

Any hints?

Comment: Is it possible that this is because the systems I am trying to boot are 32-bit systems? Do I need to put in an explicit description of these because they are 32-bit while the EFI is 64-bit?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by using `efibootmgr`. I don't have Windows installed, but the process should work similarly for you.

If you can't boot into Ubuntu, use a live version.

First make sure you have `efibootmgr` installed

`$ sudo apt-get install efibootmgr`

Then check the partitions from which EFI can boot

```
$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0082
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Mac OS X
Boot0082* 
BootFFFF*
```

In my case it lists 4 partitions. `Boot0000` is the Ubuntu partition where Grub is installed, by default I want to boot this partition.

I found out that `Boot0080` is the recovery partition of the old Mavericks installation, while `Boot0081` is the Yosemite recovery partition. The partition where Yosemite is *actually* installed, **in my case**, is `Boot0082`

Grub is not able to load Mac OS X directly, but I can configure EFI to load the Mac OS X partition when Grub exits.

So I've run

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0082
```

Which, to recap, means `Boot0000`, where Grub is installed, will be run first, then if you exit grub (by pressing `c` end then typing the command `exit`) you can boot into Mac OS X

To make the process of booting Mac OS X more comfortable you can add an entry to the Grub boot menu which exits and thus starts Mac OS X. Just edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and append the following

```
menuentry "Exit to Max OS X" {
  exit
}
```

And reload the Grub configuration with

```
sudo update-grub
```

All should work

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be simple: The Yosemite upgrade had overwritten the "fake" MBR partition table with a new one which did not contain the existing windows and Ubuntu partitions.

The solution:
1) Boot into the rEFInd command shell
2) Execute the command gptsync_x64.efi
3) Answer the questions with a Y:
    (paraphrased) the partition tables do not match,
                  would you like to see what it would like like if I fixed it?
   and            would you like me to fix it?

I then rebooted and everything is good.

Going forward, OSX is 64-bit only, and the early Intel-Macs cannot run systems later than Lion. But the 64-bit EFI boots 32-bit OS-es jsut fine.